# Chrome Pending Issues

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html5-video

I have an issue that only occurs in Chrome (latest version) - it does not occur in FireFox/Opera.

The WordPress site I have locally uses some jQuery logic to build out slides and each slide has a quiz that is displayed where there are questions with true and false answers.

Clicking on an answer, regardless of whether it is true or false, triggers a `videoPlay.get(0).play();` where videoPlay is a variable as defined here:

```
var videoPlay = jQuery(this).find('.question-video');
```

This should in turn play the selected answers corresponding HTML5 video....if true you go to the next slide, if false you go back to the question and keep going until you select the right answer.

The problem is that it works for a bit, but when you progress far enough into the slides OR if you click on too many false answers even on the first slide, the explainer video for that question is listed as `pending` in Chrome's network tools and it says the initiator is `videoPlay.get(0).play();`.

There are no console errors at all. When I visit the video file directly in a new tab it plays as expected, but within the context of the quiz program, it behaves as explained here and is just infinitely pending.

I even have `preload` set to `none` on all of the videos. The markup for them is as such:

```
<video class="question-video" preload="none">
    <source src="path/to/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Does anyone know why this would happen in Chrome?

Comment: Sound like a bug. Did you try with preload set to auto?

Comment: I will try that, but may I ask what the difference would be? And do you mean a bug in my code or Chrome?

Comment: @K3N I tried what you said and no luck. :( I can post a link to my jQuery if you could take a look?

Comment: Ah, no I meant bug in Chrome (assumption as there is no code to see). Auto uses an "optimistic" strategy to load the data hinting you want the entire video downloaded (the browser need not do this though). I would also suggest checking in Chrome Canary to see if the problem is still there.

Comment: Sure, a fiddle would help.

Comment: @K3N Weird....it works fine in Chrome Canary...but I am trying to launch this next week for a client and can't really wait for that. Here is the jQuery code: https://jsfiddle.net/5rzzz94s/ and here is a jsbin where you can actually replicate the issue in Chrome's latest version if you click on enough videos...just drag the seeker to the end to end it then go down and click false 3-4 times..http://output.jsbin.com/bupifiruqa/1

Comment: edit: or click true...then you will just see it hang forever...

Comment: @K3N Did you have a chance to look? (:

Comment: I only had a chance to look at it quickly. There are about 10-11 (?) elements in a single page. My first though was to reuse just a single element. I could not reproduce the error though. I'll check back later, hopefully someone else can take a look at this as well.

Comment: @K3N I can reproduce the issue on my local copy in the latest version of Chrome. All of the elements are the same in the JSBin version (latest one is here: http://output.jsbin.com/patipal), but on my local copy all of the elements have different videos, but the same issue as in the JSBin. When you click on 4-5 videos to eventually one won't play and you will see a "pending" issue in the chrome network inspector. Is this because of the # of sockets/issues with chrome? I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: @K3N I found the issue!!!! It has to do with the max number of sockets being in use (6) in the latest version of Chrome. I checked this by going to chrome://net-internals/#sockets - but how do I close a socket without completely removing a video? ....e.g. I do not want to do videoPlay.prop('src',''); and videoPlay.find('source').remove(); and then videoPlay.remove(); because that will prevent you from being able to click on the video again and play it...